# How to interpret the result of a SELECT...JOIN...INTO in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, join, psql

I would like to select a single joined row and then store it in a PLSQL variable I could then use in some sane way.

My best bet seemed the `RECORD` type, but it didn't get me anywhere:

```
DECLARE cur_acct_and_balance RECORD;
BEGIN
  -- we start from _acct
  SELECT INTO cur_acct_and_balance *
  FROM Accounts acct JOIN Balances bal ON acct.id = bal.account_id
  WHERE acct.id = _acct.id AND bal.currency = _currency;

  -- raise the variable, maybe we learn something...
  raise exception '%', cur_acct_and_balance;
```

so... I managed to put *something* in the `cur_acct_and_balance` variable, but what? :D I tried raising the resulting variable as an exception, to inspect it, but no luck in interpreting the results:

```
ERROR:  (5707,5706,,,"{""logid"":""A/1/2/0""}","2017-05-19 21:44:40.672074","2017-05-19 21:44:40.672074",3170,5707,0,191,"2017-05-19 21:44:40.662101","2017-05-19 21:44:40.662101")
```

Which was very not useful. If I try to evaluate it as `cur_acct_and_balance.acct IS NOT NULL` I get

```
ERROR:  record "cur_acct_and_balance" has no field "acct"
```

If I try to evaluate it as `cur_acct_and_balance.acct.id IS NOT NULL` I get

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "acct"
```

I found no good resources googling, so I'm hoping good people here can be of some assistance ^_^

**UPDATE**

For now I simply rewrote the function to not use joins, but I'm still interested to know, I'm guessing a join variant should be more performant.

Comment: Use `jsonb` type instead of untyped `record` to get more abilities to manage it: `declare cur_acct_and_balance jsonb; ... select to_jsonb(*) into cur_acct_and_balance from ...;`

Comment: Good point, I'll play with this <3

Answer (score 1):

Your record will not have reference to original tables, but only to its columns. You're joining two tables in just one set. So you must access your columns this way:

```
cur_acct_and_balance.column_name
```

Your IF statement:

```
IF cur_acct_and_balance.id IS NOT NULL THEN
      --If body
END IF
```

Comment: Problem is, there's two tables in the join with the ID column, how can the engine know which one we mean? We expect every resultset row to be 1 account and 1 balance joined together, both always present, or none

Comment: Defining an alias to these columns would resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions:

```
create temp table a on commit drop as select 1 as x, 2 as y;
create temp table b on commit drop as select 'a'::text as x, 'b'::text as y;
do $$
declare
  r record;
  j jsonb;
begin
  -- Explicyt type conversion
  select a.*, row(b.*)::b as b into r from a,b;
  raise info '%, %, %', r, r.y, (r.b).x; -- Note parenthesizes

  -- Columns aliases
  select a.x as a_x, a.y as a_y, b.x as b_x, b.y as b_y into r from a,b;
  raise info '%, %', r, r.b_y;

  -- JSONB
  select to_jsonb(t.*) into j from (select a.*, to_jsonb(b.*) as b from a,b) as t;
  raise info '%, %', j, j->'b'->>'x';
end $$;
```

Result:

```
INFO:  (1,2,"(a,b)"), 2, a
INFO:  (1,2,a,b), b
INFO:  {"b": {"x": "a", "y": "b"}, "x": 1, "y": 2}, a
```